# Gulp requires older version of Nodejs

Tags: node.js, gulp

Working through the setting up of a project that requires the use of gulp. However I am getting the error:

> Your dev environment is running NodeJS version v10.13.0 which does not meet the requirements for running this tool. This tool requires a version of NodeJS that matches >=8.9.4 <9.0.0

It seems strange that I should have to go back a version to make the latest version of gulp (3.9.1) work.

Not familiar with this at all so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, gulp 3.9.1 is not the latest version, there is a gulp4.xx. which you need to use with node10.   npm install 'gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0' --save-dev

Comment: Thanks. Finaly managed to get v4.0 installed but still get the same error.

Comment: Hmmm, did you uninstall gulp 3.9.1 first?  Sorry, I should have mentioned that.  And I assume it requires a restart of your IDE.

Comment: Yes - uninstalled everything and got 4.0 loaded. Turns out that gulp serve does not work on 4 (if I have understood what I have read correctly). So it is back to gulp 3.9.1 and using node 8.12.0 and all seems to be working.

Comment: I uninstalled Node 10.13.0 and installed Node 8.12.0. Then ran npm rebuild node-sass for proper environment binding and i ran like charm.